# When I play music from a playlist, how do I get back to the playlist?

Tags: ios, apple-music, playlist

For example, in the Apple Music "For You" section, I start playing one of the suggested playlists. While that is playing, I am browsing around in Apple Music looking at other things (but still listening to the original playlist).

Now I want to go back to the original playlist. I can't find any way to do that, short of opening up "For You" and scrolling through it trying to find the original thing I tapped. (And it doesn't help that the "For You" section refreshes itself while I am scrolling, making it a frustrating moving target.)

Comment: Have you tried the back arrow? Goes back in history no matter what tab you were in.

Comment: On iOS I've tried the swipe-down and swipe-back actions. But that only works if I haven't "done anything". E.g. if I have scrolled around in "For You" to look at other suggestions, now I can't quickly get back to the original playlist, and of course "For You" may have refreshed so the original playlist might not even be there.

Comment: Ahh oops I thought this was OSX question, sorry, no back arrow lol.

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered you can click the “artist name - album name” on the now playing screen. Then click the playlist.
[image: Click artist name on now playing screen.]

Comment: This is working for me in iOS 12.3.1 as of June 2019 (seems they keep changing things). In addition to that in the screenshot, I get "Go to Artist"

Answer (score 1):

Tap on the mini player, then on the "Up Next" button on the right:

[image: mini player, up next]

You can edit the "Up Next" list on that screen.

When finished you can tap on "Done".

It shows the following 20 tracks, not the full playlist.

Comment: Well that’s better than nothing. If only you could see the original playlist.

Comment: @Nate you can always go to My Music > Playlists and look for it

Comment: If the playlist was from “For You” or “New” then it won’t be in my playlists unless I’ve specifically added it.

Comment: Right. Pretty confusing. Haven't seen the iOS 10 music app but it is supposedly redesigned. Hopefully this is one of the things they solved.

Answer (score 1):

Ask siri which playlist is playing, works for me!

Comment: Not an awful answer. Can you just add a picture and some more explaining on what this allows you to do, maybe some possible limitations.

Comment: Does it take you back to the playlist or just tell you the name of it?

Comment: Siri didn't work for me, response: "I'm not sure what playlist this is." iOS 12.1.4  
The @Mr_Moneybags answer works for me.